# Mercury’s death comes halfway through

Tags: meaning-in-context

*Sacha Baron Cohen allegedly walked from the movie when May outlined a story to him where **Mercury’s death comes halfway through, “and the band goes from strength to strength”**. May denied that was the case, and if ever it was, they thankfully changed tack.*

Source: 
https://www.theguardian.com/film/2018/oct/23/bohemian-rhapsody-review-freddie-mercury-biopic-bites-the-dust

I am not sure if I properly understand the passage in bold. Does it mean that May (who denies it) wanted the film about Mercury not to end with the death of Mercury? So in the planned script, the death of Mercury would come in the middle of the movie and the second part would be devoted to the story of the remaining members.

Comment: That would seem to be the case, alhough I don't know how this is a question for ELL apart fom the question itself "wanted the film about Mercury did not end with the death of Mercury"  could be "wanted the film about Mercury not to end with his death".

Comment: May *wanted the film about Mercury **to** not end* with his death (not "did"). And **be devoted** ( not "devote") : *... the second part would **be devoted**...*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Sacha Baron Cohen allegedly walked from the movie when May outlined a story to him where Mercury’s death comes halfway through, “and the band goes from strength to strength”.

What Cohen didn't like:
The fact that Mercury dies half-through and the movie shows the band going from one success to another.

In other words, the part about the main character Mercury is short lived in the movie.

It makes sense that Cohen walked away as the biopic was supposed to be about Mercury. You don't kill off a biopic's main character half-way through a movie....

Comment: I think you meant to say "What Cohen didn't like."  May was the one who supposedly proposed that story to Cohen.